# In composer.json is there a way to specify the repo to use for an individual package?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working in PHP and there are two repositories from which I am pulling packages.  Call them Repository1 and Repository2.  Repository1 has the higher priority.  One of the packages I need (PackageA) is in both repositories.  I need version X, which resides in Repository2.  Since Repository1 doesn't have version X, I have to make Repository1 not canonical.  Another package (PackageB) also exists in both repositories.  Furthermore, both repositories have a version Y.  The packages are not indentical.  When I specify `"PackageB": "Y"` it is giving me the package from Repository2, but I need the one in Repository1.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.repo1.net",
        "canonical": false
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.repo2.net",
    }
],
"require": {
    "PackageA": "X",
    "PackageB": "Y"
}
```

So my question is, given that Repository1 can't be canonical, is there a way to tell composer to pull PackageB from Repository1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH, I think this is like asking if there is a way to hit yourself with a hammer and not have it hurt. The answer is stop hitting yourself with a hammer. The solution for this problem is for me to clean up the mess of two repos with identical packages.

To clarify, I still don't know if there is a way to specify repos at a per-package level, but I suspect the answer is no.  I don't think there is any "reasonable" use case for such functionality.  My case of having two packagist repos with non-matching package with the same name and version is not reasonable.  What I did to solve it was figure out which package we wanted to use and either rename or remove the packages in our private packagist.

Comment: Not a relevant answer!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).